# What is this potted plant with small purple berries?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I bought this very tiny plant from a hospital.  I was visiting someone and it caught my eye.  It was about an inch or less high when I got it.  The person in the shop told me that it was an orange tree plant.  I was excited to think that one day I would have an orange tree plant so I nurtured this plant and re-potted it many times.  My father, who knows some things about planting, told me that it was not an orange tree plant, but he did not know what this plant was.

About two weeks ago, I noticed these purple berries growing.  I think that they are beautiful, but it really got me to thinking.  What kind of plant do I have?  Here I am.  Can anyone tell me what is this plant?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. I wonder if you could tell us which country you bought this in. Also a close up of the leaf veins and the berry would be helpful.

Comment: if you bend the tip of a leaf or scratch the bark is there a white sap?

Answer (score 2):

I found your post while looking for the same plant. A friend of mine found hers growing in a pot with a houseplant that she had purchased in SC. 
I believe it is allspice. 
http://nurserylive.com/buy-aromatic-plants-online-in-india/all-spice-plants-in-india
We think it fell into a pot at the nursery, then was sold to the  store she bought it from.
If you kept scrolling after clicking the link, it has a pretty informative description after the first paragraph. 
When her berries come again we are going pick the unripe ones, dehydrate them, and grind to see if they actually smell like allspice.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same plant and have been dying to know what it is!

I think I FINALLY figured it out: it's [Ardisia elliptica (shoebutton tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardisia_elliptica)

Comment: Please explain **why** you think it's _Ardisia elliptica_.